# Who calls the Static Constructor of a Class

Tags: c#, static, cil

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
B b = new B();

public class A
{
    static A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static ctor A");
    }
    public A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ctor A");
    }
}
public class B:A
{
    static B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static ctor B");
    }
    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ctor B");
    }
}
```

It is Obviously that the Output is :
Static ctor B
Static ctor A
ctor A
ctor B
So my question is Who invokes the Static ctor? When I searching this question, I always get the
answer that "The system(CLR) calls the static ctor before any instance of this class appear"
I peek inside the IL as well, still, I can't get a clue when static ctor invokes and who calls it.

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void '<Main>$' (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Header size: 12
    // Code size: 18 (0x12)
    .maxstack 1
    .entrypoint
    .locals init (
        [0] class B b
    )

    IL_0000: ldstr "Hello, World!"
    IL_0005: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000a: nop
    IL_000b: newobj instance void B::.ctor()
    IL_0010: stloc.0
    IL_0011: ret
} // end of method Program::'<Main>$'
```

In Main() the B::ctor() is called, and in B::ctor(), A::ctor() is called,however,I didn't aware
of any calls of the static ctor which is called cctor

My first guess is it happens in .locals init part, but after several test ,it proves it's not.
Then I think maybe the calling is because the ldarg0 of the ctor method

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void .ctor () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20a8
    // Header size: 1
    // Code size: 20 (0x14)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: call instance void A::.ctor()
    IL_0006: nop
    IL_0007: nop
    IL_0008: ldstr "ctor B"
    IL_000d: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0012: nop
    IL_0013: ret
} // end of method B::.ctor
```

Above is the B::ctor method, notice ldarg.0 in the first line, as far as I know ldarg.0 refers
to "this",so does it mean it is a "instance" of this class? In order to refer to "this",the CLR
calls the static ctor?

I want to know who calls cctor in C#

Comment: This is for .NET 4, so it might be different in .NET 6, but in any case an interesting read: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/

Answer (score 0):

In c#, static constructors are called by the CLR.
This is documented in the Remarks section of [Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors):

> - A static constructor cannot be called directly and is only meant to be
>   called by the common language runtime (CLR). It is invoked
>   automatically.
> - The user has no control on when the static constructor
>   is executed in the program.
> - A static constructor is called
>   automatically. It initializes the class before the first instance is
>   created or any static members declared in that class (not its base
>   classes) are referenced. A static constructor runs before an instance
>   constructor. A type's static constructor is called when a static
>   method assigned to an event or a delegate is invoked and not when it
>   is assigned. If static field variable initializers are present in the
>   class of the static constructor, they're executed in the textual order
>   in which they appear in the class declaration. The initializers run
>   immediately prior to the execution of the static constructor.